# XQuartz: Enable ‘Allow connections from network clients’ via command line

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, xquartz

I'd like to write a shell script that uses xquartz.

Specifically the **‘Allow connections from network clients’** checkbox at *Settings/Security* has to be checked. Is there a way to do this programmatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xquartz settings are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist`, the key you are looking for is `nolisten_tcp`.

To allow connections from network clients use

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist nolisten_tcp 0
```

To prevent connections use

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist nolisten_tcp 1
```

For both cases Xquartz must not be running while you apply the change.

PS: To look at the content of the file you can use

```
plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist
```

Comment: 's answer doesn't work for me.
Looks like the command now should be: defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 nolisten_tcp -bool true plutil -p ~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist will indeed show the nolisten_tcp is now set to 1 But the change is temporary, as soon as I do startx, it gets reset to 0.
Some others recommended adding nolisten_tcp -bool true directly to the defaultserverargs in the startx file but that has broken my startx. No solution to me as of now (sorry I can't write comments yet so this is 'answer')

Comment: I agree with you.  Doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @nohillside♦ and @dan for your answers.

In my case the command `defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist nolisten_tcp 0` had had no effect. After some investigation I've figured out that the plist filename is a bit different in my system. So the command that ultimately worked for me is:

```
defaults write org.xquartz.X11.plist nolisten_tcp -bool false
```

Note that [macosforge](https://www.macosforge.org/) has been shutdown and projects moved to other places - so removing macosforge from the default name makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`XQuartz` settings or preferences are managed from the file
`~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist`
and are managed by `XQuartz` to read and write them through the
agent `com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent`.

The undocumented clean way I found to manage this file is:

1. Quit `XQuartz`
2. Stop `com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent`:

   ```
   launchctl stop com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent
   ```
3. Make a local copy of `~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist`

   ```
   mkdir src ; cd src
   cp ~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist .
   plutil -convert xml1 org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist
   vi org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist
   ```

   just before the last line containing:

   ```
   </dict>
   ```

   insert:

   ```
           <key>nolisten_tcp</key>
           <false/>
   ```

   save and exit `vi`.
4. Copy back this local copy on the original file:

   ```
   cp org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist ~/Library/Preferences
   ```
5. Restart `com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent`:

   ```
   launchctl start com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent
   ```
6. Restart `XQuartz`

Since I wanted to make editing of this preference file as easy as possible, I made a Makefile of the process. Here is this Makefile:

```
PREF=~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist
SRC=org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist
CFD=com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent

pref:
        cp $(SRC) $(PREF)

install:
        nohup sh -c 'make kill ; make pref ; make start' &

kill:
        pkill startx
        launchctl stop $(CFD)

start:
        launchctl start $(CFD)
        sleep 5
        open /Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app
```